# Javascript: how to cover entire area?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I'm writing code for the first time with SVG. I created a small program in javascript. The rectangle does not start perfectly from the base of the area, remains a strip of light blue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
    #graphicArea {
      width: 1400px;
      background: #a7def2;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="outer-wrapper">
    <div id="graphicArea"> </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var width = 1400;
    var height = 600;
    var graphic;
    var gocceAlSec = 7;
    graphic = d3.select("#graphicArea").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("id", "graphic")
      .attr("overflow", "hidden");

    var dataset = [0];

    graphic.selectAll("rect")
      .data(dataset)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 600)
      .attr("width", 1400)
      .attr("height", 0)
      .style("fill", "blue")
      .transition()
      .duration(50000)
      .attr("height", 600)
      .attr("y", 0);

  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the background colour to the `<div>`, and because of that you'll have to deal with default margins, paddings, computed height etc...

A way simpler approach is setting the background colour to the SVG:

```
graphic = d3.select("#graphicArea").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("id", "graphic")
      .style("background", "#a7def2")
```

Here is your code with that change:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="outer-wrapper">
    <div id="graphicArea"> </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var width = 1400;
    var height = 600;
    var graphic;
    var gocceAlSec = 7;
    graphic = d3.select("#graphicArea").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("id", "graphic")
      .style("background", "#a7def2")
      .attr("overflow", "hidden");

    var dataset = [0];

    graphic.selectAll("rect")
      .data(dataset)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 600)
      .attr("width", 1400)
      .attr("height", 0)
      .style("fill", "blue")
      .transition()
      .duration(50000)
      .attr("height", 600)
      .attr("y", 0);

    function makeRain() {

      for (var i = 0; i < gocceAlSec; i++) {
        startX = Math.random() * width,
          startY = Math.random() * 100 - 100,
          endX = startX;
        endY = height + 200;
        graphic.insert("circle")
          .attr("cx", startX)
          .attr("cy", startY)
          .attr("r", 2)
          .style("fill", "blue")
          .transition()
          .duration(2000)
          .attr("cx", endX + 100)
          .attr("cy", endY)
          .remove();
      };
    }

    d3.timer(makeRain, 100);
  </script>
</body>
```

If you want to stick with the `<div>` style you can try some changes, like `max-heigh: 600px;`.

---

PS: Since this is your first D3/SVG code (by the way, kudos), here is a tip: you don't need an enter selection for the rect, not only because it's only one but mainly because the datum is meaningless. Just append the element to the container.